# Gradle constant for src/main directory

Tags: gradle

Is there predefined variable that point to `src/main` directory?

I can't find anything by grepping Gradle sources... There is `project.sourceSets.test` / `project.sourceSets.main` only...

I want to define subdirectory for specific file type. Should I just use `src/main/xsd` constant?

Answer (score 1):

A [`SourceSet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) is a logical group of Java source and resources. So everything that is not Java, is resources.

You can't change a `SourceSet` but you can add a new one

```
sourceSets {
    xsd {
        resources {
            srcDir 'path/to/xsd/files'
        }
    }
}
```

The `src/main` path can't be resolved as it's not a "thing" in the `SourceSet` scope, it only makes sense at the [`SourceDirectorySet`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.file.SourceDirectorySet.html) level (`java` and `resources` are `SourceDirectorySet`)